# Rendering not working even through command is visible in CMD log

Tags: django, ajax, post, request, rendering

I am new to django, trying to use AJAX to move data from html to views.py via AJAX, something weird is happening, data is moving but the page is not changing, new page is not getting rendered.

HTML CODE

```
    <div class="bodyclass">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for account in accounts %}
    <div class="">
        <div class="accountname">
            <button onclick="submitform('{{ account}}')" class="btn btn-info accbtn " id="{{ account }}">{{account}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div
```

JS Code

```
    <script>
    function submitform(accname){
        alert(accname);
        var csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'accounts',
            data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrf[0].value,
                'accname': accname,
            },
        });

        alert('bye');
    }
</script>
```

views.py

```
def accounts(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:        
        if request.method == 'GET':
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                account = AccountDescription.objects.all()
            else:
                account = UserAccount.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            return render(request, 'accounts.html',{'accounts':account})
        elif request.method == "POST":
            print(request.POST)
            print(request.POST.get('accname'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/clientinfo')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
```

also the cmd screenshot
[image]

Kindly let me what wrong I am doing. also let me know if any more input is required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are sending an AJAX request but not doing anything else after that. In particular, you are not reading its response. How do you expect the page to render the response?

Comment: @soxwithMonica I am redirecting it to '/clientinfo' as visible in the cmd log there is a get request for the same. I have used render(request, 'clientinfo.html') as well getting same thing.

Comment: no, django is returning a redirect response that the browser automatically follows (as you see in the django log). That doesn't change what I said before, you are sending an AJAX request and not even reading the response (the actual one, after the redirection). Where is the AJAX `onsuccess()` response handler?

Comment: ok. I understood. I have to redirect to different via JavaScript from the onsuccess() response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read ajax return output on JS File

JS Code

```
$.ajax(
            {
            type:"POST",
            url: "/checkonline",
            data:{
                    //Pass CSRF & Data
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                //Read Response Here
                //redirect user to here using javascript 
                 alert(data);
            }
        })
```

views.py

```
//Example for Return Response in JSON Format

from django.http import JsonResponse

def accounts(request):
    return JsonResponse(list({"redirect_user"}) , safe=False)
```